# Error while importing some PostgreSQL data via PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to import some data from a bunch of tables in an PostgreSQL database in another bunch of tables in another PostgreSQL database. For importing I use PHP because I need to make some data manipulation before inserting it in the new database.

All went ok until some point where there is some text which contains single quotes. I tried to escape those quotes before inserting the data and i get this error:

> ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x96 HINT: This
>   error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding
>   expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".

The encoding on the old database is SQL_ASCII, while on the new database I have UTF8.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post the query/data? Maybe casting to a different data type might be the option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you have some Windows-1252-encoded text in your old database (0x96 encodes EN DASH in that encoding).

When the server encoding is `SQL_ASCII`, PostgreSQL does not perform encoding conversion or validation; it just stores and retrieves text as you gave it.  If your old database had used `UTF8` instead, you wouldn't be having this problem.  Woulda coulda shoulda.

There's a decent chance that all of your text is in `WIN1252`, but it's possible that there's a mixture of encodings.  The easiest thing to do is assume the former and set the client encoding to `WIN1252` in your migration script:

```
pg_set_client_encoding($new_database, 'WIN1252');
```

It's important that you set this on your connection to the *new* database.  It's telling Postgres that Windows 1252-encoded text is coming in, and Postgres needs to convert it to UTF-8.

Note that if there's any UTF-8-encoded text in the old database, it will either throw an error or become [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) if you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pg_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php) when inserting in the database